# "Unexpected T_STRING" error in my PHP?

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with some PHP code I'm trying to use. I keep getting an "unexpected T_STRING" error? This is the code on my test page:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <?php
    include 'http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml';

    $current_observation = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

    echo $current_observation->location[0]->plot;
    echo $current_observation->weather[0]->plot;
    echo $current_observation->temperature_string[0]->plot;
    echo $current_observation->wind_string[0]->plot;

    ?>
```

What I'm wanting to do is pull weather data from this National Weather Service XML file, and display it in a way similar to how the NWS is doing it on that page. However, the above code returns this message: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml on line 1". Is this something I can fix? I'm new to PHP, so any help you can provide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this script should be run before the html and doctype tags, you did not finish your html code with head and body Those should always be the basic for your html webpage.

Second of all where does $xmlstr points to, you have never created the variable $xmlstr, and the webpage you include is xml so that one doesn't do it either.
If you are using your own set up webserver you could enable cUrl where you can parse the xml sourcecode, saving it into variables and showing it step by step using an array and a for-loop.
You would save the parsed data in an array like:

with cUrl you get an output which you can save in a variable, lets say $output.
from there on you would have to echo your way parsing step by step, so first you would do echo $output; so you know what the source actually looks like when using cUrl, next step is to find the specific data in that url and parse your way to that point using explode (creates arrays) and substrings, and you can save those into an array like:
$city[$cityName][$temp] or someting like that

Comment: I was just using the sample code provided here: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: You do not save the XML file to a variable, best thing to do is indeed file_gets_content({URL HERE});
another option is cUrl as stated above. Is this your first time makeing a website

Comment: I have a website, www.suncoaststormwatch.com, but I've never done anything with PHP.

Comment: a fast comment on your webpage set overflow: hidden; in your css.
php is indeed little harder and I advise you to start with some basics. have a look for file_get_contents on the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
this is the shorter easier version for cUrl, that should look like this: $xmlstr = file_get_content("http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml");, remove the include line as well and put this script above the doctype, you could remove the html temporary because you only echo php stuff and no html.

Comment: If you want to add html stuff to it you should make it look like: 
<?php
$xmlstr=file_get_content("http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml");
$current_observation=new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
?>
<!DOCTYPE etc
<html>
<head>
<title>
weather
</title>
</head>
<body>
SOME HTML TEXT HERE
<?php
echo $current_observation->location[0]->plot;
echo $current_observation->weather[0]->plot;
echo $current_observation->temperature_string[0]->plot;
echo $current_observation->wind_string[0]->plot;
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: When I try the code you have above, I get an error message saying there's an extra ";" ($xmlstr=file_get_content("weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml";);). When I take it out, I get, "Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_content() in C:\wamp\www\test-1-xml.php on line 3". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: file_get_contents();
you forgot contents with the s at the end

Comment: Oops.  Ok, so I  fixed it, and am now getting, "Warning: file_get_contents(weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\test-1-xml.php on line 3", as well as a fatal error and exeption that say the string can't be parsed as XML. I had hoped this would be simple. But that's what happens when I try do something I don't know anything about.

Comment: see your problem: $xmlstr = file_get_contents("http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml");

Comment: It seems like that's fixed, but now I just have a blank page.... I'm missing some kind of variable/id, aren't I?

Comment: how does your page looks like atm, do you have the html fixed as I said?, if so than add to the group of echos: echo $xmlstr;
This will show you the sourcecode from the xml page

Comment: :) Ok, that worked. Thanks! However, it is showing the whole file, and not just the elements that were echoed (location, current weather, temperature, and wind).

Comment: true, that means that they were not parsed/ improperly parsed, do you have: $current_observation = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); at the end of the first php block (the block before the doctype)?, you can remove that echo you added, It was just for testing purposes

Comment: Yes, I have the $current_observation part above the doctype. So now, I've just removed the echo $xmlstr; from the group of echoes in the <body> section.

Comment: and try to echo $current_observation instead, from here on it is just trial and error ;-)

Comment: Where? Are you saying it would be easier to just grab the entire file, instead of individual parts?

Comment: No, because we do not see any feedback from the parsed parts we need to traceback the problem, the easiest way to do so is to add this command in the echo block: print_r($current_observation);

Comment: Oh, ok. I echoed that, and this is part of what it returned: SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 1.0 ) [credit] => NOAA's National Weather Service [credit_URL] => http://weather.gov/ [image] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [url] => http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif [title] => NOAA's National Weather Service [link] => http://weather.gov ) [suggested_pickup] => 15 minutes after the hour [suggested_pickup_period] => 60 [location] => Tampa International Airport, FL [station_id] => KTPA  [latitude] => 27.97 [longitude] => -82.53 [observation_time]

Comment: you can tell this page does not have the wanted array keys
location[0],weather[0],temperature_string[0],wind_string[0]
because you do not see them in the ['{this is the key}'] part, and that is the reason you got an empty echo in the first place

Comment: I have an empty echo because the XML file does not have the array keys? If that is the case, this won't do what I want it to, will it?

Comment: nope it wont, yu want location: available:
weather: unavailable
temperature_string: unavailable
wind_string: unavailable

Comment: And there's no other way to do this through PHP? I've figured out the code to do it with an XMLHttpRequest, but that returns a browser security alert.

Comment: If their website doesnt send you the information, you cannot do anything in php, if you find a webpage that send that specific information, you can do it

Comment: Ok. Well, thanks for all the help you've given me. It is greatly appreciated. I'd vote you up, but my account doesn't have that privilege yet. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, i found the problem:
echo $current_observation->location[0];
echo $current_observation->weather[0];
echo $current_observation->temperature_string[0];
echo $current_observation->wind_string[0];
you had to remove ->plot
then it works

Comment: I removed all the "->plot", and now I have the t_string issue again.

 print_r($current_observation);   
  echo $current_observation location[0];  
  echo $current_observation weather[0]; 
  echo $current_observation temperature_string[0]; 
  echo $current_observation wind_string[0];

Comment: this is how it should look like:
 echo $current_observation->location[0];
 echo "<br/>";
 echo $current_observation->weather[0];
 echo "<br/>";
 echo $current_observation->temperature_string[0];
 echo "<br/>";
 echo $current_observation->wind_string[0];

Comment: It works perfectly!

It returned: 

Tampa International Airport, FL
Overcast
73.0 F (22.8 C)
from the East at 10.4 gusting to 16.1 MPH (9 gusting to 14 KT)

Thanks so much for all the help. I've been trying to figure this out for the past two weeks using various methods, and I've spent more than a few hours with things that I thought would work but didn't. Now I have a reliable method to use for these types of things in the future.

Comment: You can add an input field for the city code, and then make it look up that city + temperature etc

Answer (score 5):

The `include` function is used to include other php scripts. To get the contents of the xml file you'll have to use `file_get_contents`

```
$xmlstr =  file_get_contents('http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml');

$current_observation = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

echo $current_observation->location[0]->plot;
echo $current_observation->weather[0]->plot;
echo $current_observation->temperature_string[0]->plot;
echo $current_observation->wind_string[0]->plot;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you understand the purpose of `include`. To get the contents of a file, use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). As such:

```
$xmlstr = file_gets_contents('http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml');
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a T_STRING error the moment you include any illegally quoted text strings in your PHP source.

PROBABLE CAUSE:

You can't "include" non-PHP text in a PHP source file.

SOLUTION:

Use PHP "fopen()" (or equivalent) to read and parse the file your interested in.

Better, if the file is XML, then use PHP XML to parse it:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would try to assign something to the variable you want to parse, because just inluding the file won't work as it's not a PHP script that can be interpreted as well and included in the output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <?php
    $xmlstr = simplexml_load_file('http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KTPA.xml');
    $current_observation = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

    echo $current_observation->location[0]->plot;
    echo $current_observation->weather[0]->plot;
    echo $current_observation->temperature_string[0]->plot;
    echo $current_observation->wind_string[0]->plot;

    ?>
```